# how to format elements diffrently depending on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I am an absolute beginner.
I've got a JavaScript project in which I must 'format specific elements differently depending on the type of browser used'

and I have no idea what to do with that. Should I check out how the code displays in diffrent browsers and then figure out how to optimize it or is there some kind of guide that shows which elements display diffrently?

I would be really grateful for any answer.

Comment: This link can be helpful in checking what browsers can do what - but you will find that the majority of the most common-used ones implement almost all of CSS3. Incidentally, 'browser sniffing' to find out what browser is actually being used is not always reliable.

Comment: Without a more specific definition of what is meant by *"format specific elements differently"* this question is very unclear. Modern browsers use the same html spec so formatting the code itself wouldn't make sense. Perhaps it means style the display of some elements differently depending on browser?

Comment: Yes, it's probably about that.

Comment: You might want to study some CSS basics tutorials for a starter. Then use the answer below to change different classes depending on `navigator.userAgent` values

Comment: Thanks for commitment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to detect [the `navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) to get the name of a browser.

[https://caniuse.com/ is a webpage](https://caniuse.com/) you can check to determine if a certain feature is supported by a browser.

Sara Cope wrote [an article about the "appearance property"](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/) that you might find helpful for disabling default styling of HTML element.